# Set cookie with taxonomy name

Tags: cookies

I know that a should set a cookie before any output.

I want to set a cookie with the actual page's taxonomy name. 
To get the taxonomy name I am using `get_query_var('taxonomy)`.

The problem is:

If I hook the cookie creation into `init` the `get_query_var` returns empty. If I hook it too late I get a `headers already sent` error.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I do have a select field to sort page results (price asc/desc, title asc/desc). To reorder the items I need to re-run the query and for that I need to know the taxonomy name and terms . The request to reorder the items is sent via ajax...

Comment: you could send that data with your ajax request rather than set a cookie.

Comment: There is a case when I need to set the cookies inside an other AJAX request. That's why I need cookies here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hooking on the `get_header` action hook.  That's the last action hook before headers are output.

Comment: `template_redirect` is technically the last action that is guaranteed to execute before output. whether or not `get_header` is called before output starts is theme-dependent and may not work consistently across all themes.